# Send my .php output to a curl command that messages me on telegram using a bot

Tags: php, bash, curl, bots, telegram

I have the following cron executed every few minutes:

```
*/8 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/xxx/yyyy.php >> /home/xxx/zzzz.log
```

Currently its output is being stored in the `.log` file. But I want to be able to send the output to me as messages via a telegram bot.

I made a bot already and have the api keys, but I'm unsure how to connect them.

On the telegram api docs, it says I can use curl to have the bot send me a message by doing the following in a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

CHATID="1234"
KEY="abcd"
TIME="10"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage"
TEXT="Hello world"

curl -s --max-time $TIME -d "chat_id=$CHATID&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=$TEXT" $URL >/dev/null
```

adding curl after >> obviously doesn't work. How would this be done?

Comment: PHP has full cURL support. Have your `/home/xxx/yyyy.php` do the telegram notification.

Comment: that wont catch any PHP errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the output of the PHP script to the `TEXT` shell variable

```
CHATID="1234"
KEY="abcd"
TIME="10"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage"
TEXT=$(usr/local/bin/php -f /home/xxx/yyyy.php)
# URL-encode some special characters
TEXT=${TEXT//%/%25}
TEXT=${TEXT//&/%26}
TEXT=${TEXT//=/%3D}
TEXT=${TEXT// /%20}
curl -s --max-time $TIME -d "chat_id=$CHATID&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=$TEXT" "$URL" >/dev/null
```

Put the above in a shell script and run that from `cron` instead of running the PHP script directly.

If you also want it sent to the log file, you can use the `tee` command:

```
TEXT=$(usr/local/bin/php -f /home/xxx/yyyy.php | tee -a /home/xxx/zzzz.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your cron output to a script, or a command by using a pipe (`|`)
here is an example :

```sh
*/8 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/xxx/yyyy.php | tee /home/xxx/zzzz.log | /home/xxx/telegram.sh
```

This will write the output of your command to /home/xxx/zzzz.log and send it to the stdin of the script.